# do we need to explicitly sanitize strong params in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sanitize

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
....

  def sanitize(value)
     ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(value.try(:strip)).gsub('&amp;', '&').gsub('&gt;', '>').gsub('&lt;', '<') if value.present?
  end

end
```

and in a resource

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
...
 def update
  if current_user.update(update_users_params)
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end

private


 def update_users_params
    params.require(:user).permit(username: sanitize(params[:user] [:username]),
                  location: sanitize(params[:user][:location]))
 end
```

here location and username are User model attributes.

Actual behaviour without using sanitize method:

if we add `"Hey <script type='text/javascript'> alert('Hi') </script>"` to username or location input field of a user form ,after form submission it is stored as it is

```
 "Hey <script type='text/javascript'> alert('Hi') </script>"
```

do we need to sanitize these attributes for script tags before storing into database?
and

does strong params will not sanitize script tags from those attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Rails will save the input as is, but it will always escape it when working with it.

You'll need to explicitly call `raw` or `html_safe` for unsanitized (html/script) strings.

Comment: That's true,but what if you need to serve the stored result to other platforms like an API service that serves to android or IOS.

Comment: Just depends how you pass it. If you just passed `params[:my_param_name]` to the API/service it would be escaped by default.

Comment: Its not escaped in the database, just when you call/use `params` or the model attributes.

Comment: raw or html_safe wouldn't work. Rails also comes with sanitize() method. You need to call sanitize() method even on model attributes.Also params are not escaped even when you call it in any helper or view itself. Strong params are sanitized to prevent from any SQL query inject,so that's not the case here.